# Loading duplicate files with ImportError in Ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a VBA code which is loading the files from the folder but it ends up loading each file two times but the duplicated one has Import errors.

[image]

Here is my VBA code

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Public Function import_data_files()

Dim report_path As String
Dim filename As String

report_path = "C:\Users\greencolor\Company & Co\Desktop\Autoreport\So_load\"

filename = Dir(report_path & "*.csv", vbDirectory)



Do While filename <> vbNullString

DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , Trim(Replace(filename, ".csv", "")), report_path & filename, True
filename = Dir


Loop


MsgBox "Data files imported! Report is updated!", vbInformation



End Function
```

Comment: This is usually caused by invalid data conversions. Best approach is to link the file, run an import query where you can shape the data as you wish and then remove the linked file.

Comment: I want this to be automated, and dont want to shape the data every time I run the import query

Comment: Not seeing why files would import twice. Have you step debugged? Where are you calling function?

Comment: after doing some research based on the ImportError table there was a column that had different data types in ( Numbers and Number and Integer mix). I read somewhere that Access looks at the first 8 rows of the source data and tries to figure out what the destination data type is based on that. Simple what I did was I dropped that column since it does not change anything to me. But for someone who its matters [https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/type-conversion-failure-with-excel-data-import.957897/] can read this